# Loading dbpedia to virtuoso

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, dbpedia, virtuoso

I downloaded dbpedia n-quads data from (http://km.aifb.kit.edu/projects/btc-2012/dbpedia/). I am trying to load BTC data to Virtuoso using:

```
   DB.DBA.TTLP_MT(file_to_string_output('/var/lib/virtuoso-opensource-6.1/db/data-0.nq'),'','graph iri',512);
```

I am getting the following error:

```
*** Error RDFXX: [Virtuoso Driver][Virtuoso Server]Bad datatype code: DB.DBA.RDF_OBJ_ADD (256, POINT(7.2858 49.0797), 257)
at line 20 of Top-Level:
DB.DBA.TTLP_MT(file_to_string_output('/var/lib/virtuoso-opensource-6.1/db/data-0.nq'),'','graph iri',512)
```

I am unable to understand as to what is going wrong. Can someone please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by installing virtuoso 7

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the BTC datasets with the [Virtuoso RDF Bulk loader](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtBulkRDFLoader) which has specific checks for loading the BTC datasets